# Tuleap - How to modify details or card color in the Cardwall view?

Tags: tuleap

Is it possible to include different fields or to change the color of the card, based on a given field (type, team, priority?)

Answer (score 0):

In the tracker that corresponds to your card type (for instance User stories) Admin > Semantic you have a "Card semantic" where you can define the fields you want to see on a card.

If you choose to put a field of type "select box" with values that have color, those colors will be rendered on the card.